# Discord.js - ReferenceError: join is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was trying to organize my commands to categories but I get an error when running my bot:

```js
const getDirectories = source => fs.readdirSync(source).map(name => join(source, name)).filter(isDirectory);
                                                                    ^
ReferenceError: join is not defined
```

[image]

I have commands stored as categories like shown in the image above and the code for the main file is:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const { token, prefix } = require('./config.json');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const db = require ('quick.db');

const client = new Discord.Client
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
// First get the category directories
const isDirectory = source => fs.lstatSync(source).isDirectory();
const getDirectories = source => fs.readdirSync(source).map(name => join(source, name)).filter(isDirectory);

// Then load the commands
getDirectories(__dirname + '/commands').forEach(category => {
  const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(category).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

  for(const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./${category}/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
  }
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`ready!.`);
    console.log(token);
    
    // Activities  
    const activities_list = [ 
        `Serving Tacos | .help`,
        `Preparing Orders | .help`
    ];
    
    setInterval(() => {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1);
        client.user.setActivity(activities_list[index]);
    }, 10000);
});
// rest of the code
```

Comment: You have never defined or imported `join`. What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're trying to use `path.join`. Don't forget to import the `path` library:

```js
const path = require('path')
```

And use it as `path.join(source, name)`. Or get the `join` method by destructuring the `path`:

```js
const {join} = require('path')
```

And use as `join(source, name)`.

Comment: ah thanks i forgot to import the library but now i get another error but thanks anyway

Comment: You're welcome. Have you fixed that new error?

Comment: it keeps telling me in the console "Error: Cannot find module './C:\Users\Aoshey\Desktop\Taco Bot\commands\economy/balance.js'" even tho balance.js already exists idk whats wrong

Comment: That's a weird path. It looks like it starts as a relative path (`./`) then an absolute path(`C:\\Users\...`). How did you `require`d that?

Comment: the bot's folder is on my desktop i don't quite understand what you are trying to say sorry i'm new to coding

Comment: How do you import `balance.js`?

Comment: I can't post long codes on comments so here https://pastebin.com/UeBDtWfu

Comment: You should probably remove the `./` from the `require(...`. If it doesn't solve the issue, feel free to open a new question and I'll look at it ;)

Comment: oh thanks so much it worked after removing the `./` thanks so much